# Сделать socket.io глобальным

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, express, socket.io

Есть app.js

```
    var express = require('express')
        , http = require('http');
    var app = express();
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    server.listen(8080);
```

В нем есть обработчик маршрута(в котором мы создаем соединение сокета):

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
    next();
}, function (req, res) {
    connection.list(function (err, result) {
        io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.emit('dataEvent', result);
        });
    });
    console.log('Hello');
});
```

Внимание! Как в другой обработчик маршрута передать сокет? Например в этот, таким образом, чтобы **my other event** сработало:

```
app.post('/register', function (req, res) {

    var groupEvents = req.body.groupEvents,
        startEvents = req.body.startEvents,
        endEvents = req.body.endEvents,
        nameEvents = req.body.nameEvents,
        colorEvents = req.body.colorEvents;

    var result = {
        id_group: groupEvents,
        dt_start: startEvents,
        dt_end: endEvents,
        name: nameEvents,
        color: colorEvents
    }

        socket.on('my other event', function (result) {
           console.log(result);
        });

    connection.addPost(result);
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

*P.S global socket = socket; не предлагать ( работает через раз)*
Как создать  io.sockets.on('connection' чтобы можно было аккуратно пользоваться socket-ом.

Comment: не очень понятно, какое отношение этот POST имеет к событию из сокета,  разве что вам зачем то нужно во время ожидания ответа, передать что-то из сокета и сформировать ответ в зависимости от этого. Если нужно запустить ожидание события из конкретного соединения, по посту, то нужно как-то собрать коллекцию этих соединений и вешать обработчик на все такие, либо на выбранный (каким образом ?).

Comment: Грубо говоря, скорее всего, вам нужна коллекция сессий, и при установке соединения по сокету, вам нужно эту сессию записать в некую карту, в которой во время поста вы сможете найти эту сессию, взять соответствующий сокет и повесить на него обработчик (btw, надо ещё и проверить нет ли его уже)

Comment: зачем всё это нужно, когда "register" можно вызвать через socket - та ещё загадка.

Comment: в данном случае body-parser собирает данные и кидает их в базу, параллельно сокет их кидает на клиент.Но как и сказано в заголовке вопроса, проблема стоит совершенно в другом. А именно: не важно какой метод маршрутизатора post get use, будь то просто функция; socket.on() или socket.emit() не работают без io.on("connection" fun (socket) { тут работает}. Как не прибегать к io.on ("connection" fun) а напрямую пользоваться socket.on('my other event', function (result) {
           console.log(result);
        }); ЧТО ДЛЯ ПРИМЕРА ПОКАЗАНО У МЕНЯ В APP.POST(пока что в данном примере не работает)

Comment: Вы понимаете, что конкретный сокет связан с конкретным клиентом? Вам нужно описать эту связь, это и будет ответом на ваш вопрос.